# NodeJS webpack building in docker container

Tags: node.js, caching, docker, webpack, yarnpkg

I read this about [long-term caching](https://medium.com/@okonetchnikov/long-term-caching-of-static-assets-with-webpack-1ecb139adb95) and tried to implement this in my project, but the manifest file generates wrong links to assets when I'm trying to build it in docker container, but generation process works well.

**Dockerfile.web**

```
FROM node:8.2.1-alpine

WORKDIR /web

ADD /tmp/app.tar.gz /web

# At the end node_modules will be removed because of bug with npm prune.
# In this case we need re-install production-only deps to reduce container weight.
RUN yarn install && \
yarn run build-production && \
rm -rf node_modules && \
yarn install --production && \
rm -rf src

RUN adduser -D mySecretUser
USER mySecretUser
```

**Anyone know what it can be, why building in docker container is different?**

*I tried to remove all images, switch off docker container caching, remove `dist` directory before generation – not works.*

Comment: A bit more details on how they different show the expected one and show the generated one for us to visualize

Comment: Thanks Tarun! I found the problem in my docker-compose building script. I'll write answer on comment below

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem was introduced by my building script which uses docker-compose.

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  # Web-server which is responsible for server-side rendering.
  # It also add additional middleware layers when proxify requests
  # for dependent systems such as API (for example enrich with auth data before sending).
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.web
    ports:
      - "${WEBSERVER_PORT}"
    env_file:
      - ./docker/web.env
    volumes:
      - assets:/web/dist/assets
    command: ["yarn", "run", "_production"]

  # Nginx used as proxy-wrapper which is placed before web-server.
  # It's resposible for static files and proxy to web-server.
  # It also can be used for proxify websocket connection to specific game server.
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.nginx
    volumes:
      - assets:/www/assets
    ports:
      - "80:${NGINX_PORT}"
    env_file:
      - ./docker/web.env
      - ./nginx/nginx.env
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "envsubst < /etc/nginx/templates/default.template > /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]

volumes:
  assets:
```

**There I have used shared volume `assets` and I didn't clear it when start docker-compose again.**

**I have using this command to build:**
`rm -rf tmp && mkdir -p tmp && tar -czvf tmp/app.tar.gz src config .babelrc mq.json postcss.config.js webpack.*.js package.json yarn.lock && export $(cat ./docker/web.env | grep -v ^# | xargs) && docker-compose -p cruiserwars build`,
where I have preparing tar.gz with sources, setting up environment variables and then use `docker-compose.yml` to build my project. But there I forgot to remove volume that has been created before...

**So solution will be to have this command instead:**
`rm -rf tmp && mkdir -p tmp && tar -czvf tmp/app.tar.gz src config .babelrc mq.json postcss.config.js webpack.*.js package.json yarn.lock && export $(cat ./docker/web.env | grep -v ^# | xargs) && docker-compose down -v && docker-compose -p cruiserwars build`,

you can see that **I have added `docker-compose down -v`** to stop containers and remove volume which has been create before.